# rpmbuild spec ignoring autogen.sh prefix

Tags: autotools, rpmbuild

I'm trying to create an RPM for libxml2, which relies on autotools for installation. I need to install to a custom directory, so in my spec file I provide a prefix value to autogen.sh:

```
%define _installdir /opt/custom/%_sensor/%{name}-%{version}/

%build
./autogen.sh  --prefix=%_installdir
make %{?_smp_mflags}

%configure

%install
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%_installdir
mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%_installdir
make install
```

However, when I run rpmbuild I see that ./configure is called with --prefix=/usr:

- ./configure --build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu --program-prefix= --disable-dependency-tracking **--prefix=/usr** --exec-prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --sbindir=/usr/sbin --sysconfdir=/etc --datadir=/usr/share --includedir=/usr/include --libdir=/usr/lib64 --libexecdir=/usr/libexec --localstatedir=/var --sharedstatedir=/var/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info

I can run the installation manually from the BUILD directory using the correct prefix without problems. This is RHEL 7.9 with rpmbuild version 4.11.3. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why do you think you need to install to a custom directory?

Comment: And why are you building your own RPM instead of using the one that RHEL already provides?

Comment: I'm deploying to constant integration server that has security requirements. Installing to the default directory is not an option.

Comment: Why are you calling `autogen.sh --prefix` (which calls `configure` in turn), then build with `make`, and then - after the build - run the `%configure` rpm macro which calls the `configure` script *again*?

Comment: Have you tried building a stock SRPM with the `_prefix` and `_foodir` rpm macros defined according to your specific needs?

Answer (score 0):

> in my spec file I provide a prefix value to autogen.sh:

There is no standard convention for the parameters to (or even the provision of) an `autogen.sh` script, but in my experience, it is unusual for them to accept parameters to configure the build.  That is `configure`'s role.

Moreover, you should avoid running `autogen.sh` as part of the build at all if you don't need to do.  You should not need to do for a project with an Autotools-based build system when starting from a full distribution tarball, but sadly, it has become relatively common to receive source packages that are deficient in this area.

> However, when I run rpmbuild I see that ./configure is called with --prefix=/usr

Yes, that is among the flags provided by the rpm `%configure` macro.  Note that so, too, are all of the specific installation-directory flags.  You can override that simply by providing your own flags.  The `configure` script will honor the last of each that appears on its command line.  You can also specify any additional configuration options you need. For example,

```
%configure \
  --prefix=%{_installdir} \
  --bindir=%{_installdir}/bin \
  --libdir=%{_installdir}/lib
```

Comment: I think I'm stuck with autogen because the tarball has no 'configure' script. I made the change you suggested to the %configure macro and it's doing something, but the call to configure now has *two* prefix values and it's still trying to install to /usr:


+ ./configure  --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --sbindir=/usr/sbin  --libdir=/usr/lib64 --libexecdir=/usr/libexec --localstatedir=/var --prefix=/opt/custom/sensor/libxml2-v2.9.9 --bindir=/opt/custom/sensor/libxml2-v2.9.9/bin --libdir=/opt/custom/sensor/libxml2-v2.9.9/lib

Comment: @user1827890, yes, there is no magic here.  `%configure` is just a macro.  It expands to the text it expands to.  Adding options adds them to the end, and it is the last one of each specified that takes effect.  If some components are still being installed into the `/usr` tree then it's either because (i) you need to override more of the specific-directory options, OR (ii) the build script is choosing installation destinations by a means other than those `configure` options.  Insufficient information is provided in the question for me to determine which.

Comment: In my experience, it *is* usual for `autogen.sh` scripts to accept parameters to configure the build. That *is* `configure`'s role, and I do not know why people write `autogen.sh` that way. OK, some `autogen.sh` appear to be legacy scripts predating `autoreconf`. My workaround is calling `autoreconf` instead of `autogen.sh` when possible, and when `autogen.sh` actually does something beyond what `autoreconf` would already do, call `autogen.sh --help` to pass the `--help` arg to the `configure` call, preventing `configure` from doing configuration during `autogen.sh`.

Comment: Well @ndim, I can only say that you must build mostly different packages than I do.  And I build (and write RPM packaging for) a lot of packages, from a wide variety of sources.  Nevertheless, if one day I run into an `autogen.sh` that both wraps a run of `configure` and performs other tasks that I cannot bypass, then I will remember your trick to pass the `--help` option to neuter the `configure` run.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like the fix was to include John Bollinger's configuration options, including more prefixes for share and man directories. Also, re-ordering the macros to make more sense helped a lot with debugging. Looking at the debug output it's apparent that the call to ./configure included both the invalid and valid prefix options, but since the valid ones came second they overrode the invalid options.

Comment: If you are calling `configure` with some parameters after `autogen.sh` has already run `configure`, the workaround for that is to run `autogen.sh --help` which passes the `--help` to `configure`, so `configure` only produces help output and does not do any configuration work. Your `%configure` macro then calls `configure` to do the configuration work. And if you set up the `_prefix` and `_sysconfdir` etc. rpm macros, `%configure` will call `configure` with the desired parameters. See `rpmbuild --showrc | less +/configure` for details.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just rebuild a standard libxml2 RPM with `--define '_prefix /opt/custom/%{_sensor}/%{name}-%{version}'` and perhaps something similar for `_sysconfdir`?

Or put

```
%global _prefix /opt/custom/%{_sensor}/%{name}-%{version}
```

at the top of the spec file which later uses `%configure`?

If you actually need to call `autogen.sh` but rely on the `%configure` rpm macro to call `configure` with the proper arguments, you might need to prevent [libxml2's `autogen.sh`](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxml2/-/blob/master/autogen.sh) from running `configure`. Either use the provided way and `export NOCONFIGURE=whatwereyouthinkingwhenyouwrotethatautogensh` (any non-empty string will do for the `autogen.sh` scripts common in the Gnome universe software packages and wherever their derivatives have spread), or run `autogen.sh` with `--help`.

BTW, I see the Fedora `libxml2.spec` file just calls `%configure` without doing any `autogen.sh` or `autoreconf` steps first, so using proper release tarballs instead of git clones or a simple tarball dump of the current git HEAD, you do not need to deal with `autogen.sh`.

If you need to see what the `%configure` RPM macro actually does, and which RPM macros it uses to configure the directory arguments to `configure` so that you can redefine them, `rpmbuild --showrc | less '+/: configure'` should help.